# Is voltage same till end , using dc battery ?

Tags: batteries

I want to find the remaining charge of  12v dc  battery . I am confused in voltage and current , either voltage remains same till battery power get finish ? ( I mean if a battery is 12 volt and is fully charge , will the power be same 12 volt after using the battery ? Or it get decrease with use ?)
Anoter , what is the mechanism beyond the remaining power show in cell phones . '?

Answer (score 5):

No, the voltage of a battery does not remain constant.  Look at the datasheet of any battery and you will instantly see that with pretty graphs:

[image]

(Energiser PP3)